# not a GROUP BY expression - CASE in aggregate function

Tags: oracle, group-by, sum, case

I am trying to group by statement like usual, but I get ORA-00979 error. What do I need to do to run that script? Every help is appreciated.
Error: [00979](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ALKt.png)

```
SELECT
  e."LastName", e."FirstName", e.ID, h."Name", h."Code", h."Loop", l."Code",
  SUM(("LoomRecord"."TotalRotations" - 
    CASE 
        WHEN lrPrev."Type"='P' THEN lrPrev."TotalRotations"
        ELSE 0
        END)) AS TotalRotations,
  SUM(("LoomRecord"."TotalRotations" - 
    CASE 
        WHEN lrPrev."Type"='P' THEN lrPrev."TotalRotations"
        ELSE 0
        END)*COALESCE(pi."UsedRuns",1)/COALESCE(pr."UsedRuns",1)*es.WagePerRotation) AS WageTotal
FROM "EmployeeShifts" es
INNER JOIN "LoomRecord" ON "LoomRecord"."LoomID" = es.LoomID AND es.StartTime<"LoomRecord"."Time" AND "LoomRecord"."Time"<=es.EndTime 
INNER JOIN "LoomRecord" lrPrev ON lrPrev.ID = 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (ORDER BY lrLast."Time" DESC,lrLast."ID" DESC) 
  FROM "LoomRecord" lrLast 
  WHERE lrLast."LoomID"="LoomRecord"."LoomID" AND (lrLast."Time"<"LoomRecord"."Time" OR (lrLast."ContractItemID"="LoomRecord"."ContractItemID" AND lrLast."Time"="LoomRecord"."Time" AND lrLast."ID"<"LoomRecord"."ID"))
)
LEFT JOIN "LoomRawRecord" lrr ON lrr."LoomID"="LoomRecord"."LoomID" AND lrr."Time"="LoomRecord"."Time"
LEFT JOIN "PlanItem" pi ON pi."PlanID"=lrr."ItemID0" AND ("LoomRecord"."Rank" IS NULL OR pi."ContractItemRank" = "LoomRecord"."Rank")
LEFT JOIN "Plan" p ON p."ID"=lrr."ItemID0" 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pi."PlanID", SUM("UsedRuns") AS "UsedRuns" FROM "PlanItem" pi GROUP BY pi."PlanID") pr ON pr."PlanID"=lrr."ItemID0"
LEFT JOIN "ContractItem" ci ON ci."ContractID"=COALESCE(pi."ContractID","LoomRecord"."ContractID") AND ci."Rank"=COALESCE(pi."ContractItemRank","LoomRecord"."Rank")
LEFT JOIN "Loom" l ON l.ID=es.LoomID
LEFT JOIN "Hall" h ON h.ID=l."HallID"
LEFT JOIN "Employee" e ON e.ID=es.EmployeeID    
WHERE es.StartTime > TO_DATE('1.11.2020') - 1 AND es.EndTime < TO_DATE('30.11.2020') + 1
group by e."LastName", e."FirstName", e.ID, h."Name", h."Code", h."Loop", l."Code"
ORDER BY l."Code",es.EmployeeID,"LoomRecord"."Time",ci."ContractID",ci."Code";
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query uses `group by` clause so you are not allowed to `order by` columns not stated there (for instance `es.EmployeeID`) since these columns actually aren't in output of `group by` clause during processing query.